# Google Cloud Platform vs GitHub pages for Static Website - different handling of index.html

Tags: jekyll, google-cloud-platform, github-pages

I'm considering hosting my static website (including a Jekyll blog) on either Google Cloud Platform (GCP) or GitHub Pages (GHP). I did a small test and noticed that GCP handles index.html file differently from GHP.

Say I have the following file structure:

```
- index.html
- folder
    - index.html
    - another.html
```

1. URL `www.example.com/folder`

GCP: Redirects to `www.example.com/folder/index.html` (index.html is undesired)

GHP: Redirects to `www.example.com/folder/` (not a problem)

2. URL `www.example.com/folder/` (with a trailing forward slash)

GCP and GHP: URL remains as `www.example.com/folder/` (desired behavior)

The behavior of GCP in case #1 is undesired. I do not want to see the index.html in the URL. Is there a way to fix this so that it works similar to the way GHP does?

Comment: Is this still an issue on GCP?

Answer (score 0):

This issue actually seems to be pretty simple to fix. Simply update your permalink to:

```
permalink: pretty
```

in your _config.yml

Source: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/156

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Jekyll permanlink requires support from the Web Server. I have already tried it. It works on GitHub Pages but not on Google Cloud Platform. Read the Jekyll documentation on Permalinks, particularly the section on [Extensionless permalinks](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#extensionless-permalinks).